# CSS Border botton line padding

Tags: html, css, padding

I am trying to add left padding to a border bottom line for a div. How can I achieve this?

[This is what i tried](http://jsfiddle.net/E7fFL/1/)

When I add padding left then both text and border bottom line moves.

```
<div class='ot'>
Black border bottom should start from 30px left    <div>

.ot{
   width:100%;
   background-color:yellow;
    border-bottom: solid;       
}
```

Comment: A border always goes over the complete width of the element; you can not do this with a border on one single element. (But you could f.e. _simulate_ the border using a positioned pseudo element – http://jsfiddle.net/E7fFL/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a background-image  and background-size. **[DEMO (with linear gradient)](http://jsfiddle.net/E7fFL/6/)**

```
.ot {
    width:100%;
    background:yellow linear-gradient(to top, black, black) no-repeat 30px bottom;
    background-size: 100% 3px;
}
```

Or a 1 pixel image : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/E7fFL/8/)**

```
.ot {
    width:100%;
    background:yellow url(http://dummyimage.com/1x1) no-repeat 30px bottom;
    background-size: 100% 3px;
}
```

*Note , a padding:bottom average fake border heifgt might be necessary*

Answer (score 3):

You could fudge it with some pseudo content.

http://jsfiddle.net/E7fFL/3/

```
div {
   width:100%;
   background-color:yellow;
   border-bottom: solid 2px;
   position: relative;
}
div:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    left: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 2px;
    content: '.';
    background: yellow;
    text-indent: -999px;
}
```

This will work provided the `height` and `bottom` properties are the equivalent and inverse equivalent, respectively, of the border width.

Comment: You can just use blank content `content: ''`, then you can remove the `text-indent: -999px`. If someone is on an extremely high resolution monitor, they may be able to see that period on the left side of their screen.

Comment: I Agree with you sdsanders.